# ARM CPU の Linux で、AWS Client VPNを使用してAmazon VPCに繋げたい

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn

Linux の AWS Client VPN を使用して、Amazon VPC に繋げたいと思っています。
しかし、AWS Client VPN は AMD64 のマシンでしかサポートされていないみたいです。
ARM CPU の場合は、どうすれば繋げられますか？

Answer (score 1):

> AWS Client VPN は AMD64 のマシンでしかサポートされていない

AWSが提供するVPNクライアントについては、たしかにAMD64版しかリリースされていないようです。

> ## 要件
>
> AWS 提供の Linux 用クライアントを使用するには、次のものが必要です。
> Ubuntu 18.04 LTS または Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (AMD64 のみ)
> [AWS が提供するクライアントを使用して接続する - AWS クライアント VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/vpn/latest/clientvpn-user/connect-aws-client-vpn-connect.html)

……しかし、AWS Client VPNは一般のVPNと同じ仕様で、AWS以外が提供するOpenVPNクライアントを利用しても接続できるようです。ですので、ARM64用にビルドされたOpenVPNクライアントを使用すれば接続できそうです。

> 次の手順は、Ubuntu コンピュータで OpenVPN アプリケーションを使用し、VPN 接続を確立する方法を示します。
>
> VPN 接続を確立するには次のコマンドを使用して OpenVPN をインストールします。
> `sudo apt-get install openvpn`
>
> VPN 管理者から受け取った設定ファイルをロードして、接続を開始します。
> `sudo openvpn --config /path/to/config/file`
>
> [OpenVPN クライアントアプリケーションを使用して接続する - AWS クライアント VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/vpn/latest/clientvpn-user/linux.html)

OpenVPNの公式サイトでも、arm64用バイナリを配布しています。

[OpenVPN Client For Linux | OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/openvpn-client-for-linux/)
[OpenVPN3Linux – OpenVPN Community](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN3Linux)

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: この回答でよろしければ、 [回答の承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をお願いします。